# equality constraints between two decision variables in QP

Tags: cgal

I am trying to use CGAL to solve a QP. I have gone over the basic example of the QP and was trying to force an equality constraint between two decision variables. If I refer the documentation,  https://doc.cgal.org/latest/QP_solver/index.html#secQPiterators, what I am trying to do it to make two (say x_i = x_j) decision variable equal. Is there a way to do that. I would really appreciate any help regarding this.

actually I cant move ahead, all those set_* functions are for setting limits, A, d, d c etc but cant find a way to make x_i = x_j. I have tried searching it online but people generally advise to get rid of the duplicate variables. However, if the problem is bigger with large number of variables, it may not be always easy to do that. I was therefore thinking if these is any way to force equality constraint between two decision variable.

Comment: There is an example for `x + y  <= 7`. Using set_r with CGAL::EQUAL, you can turn it into `x + y == 7`. Now you just need to do the same for `x_i - x_j == 0`.

Comment: ah :). thank you so much.